# PIL open() method not working with BytesIO

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

For some reason, when I try to make an image from a BytesIO steam, it can't identify the image. Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
from io import BytesIO

i = ImageGrab.grab()
i.resize((1280, 720))
output = BytesIO()
i.save(output, format = "JPEG")
output.flush()
print(isinstance(Image.open(output), Image.Image))
```

And the stack trace of the error it throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Natecat/PycharmProjects/Python/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(isinstance(Image.open(output), Image.Image))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2126, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x02394DB0>
```

I am using the Pillow implementation of PIL.

Comment: You don't need output.flush()

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Think of BytesIO as a file object, after you finish writing the image, the file's cursor is at the end of the file, so when `Image.open()` tries to call `output.read()`, it immediately gets an EOF.

You need to add a `output.seek(0)` before passing `output` to `Image.open()`.

Comment: For anyone stumbling onto this answer, it looks like this may have been resolved in a recent version of BytesIO. I am running Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_contents)) without calling seek(0) with no problems. I had a similar error but it was because the image_contents was not valid image data.

Comment: No, it's not "fixed in BytesIO". BytesIO is working as designed. Newer versions of `PIL.open()` just called `.seek(0)` unconditionally ([src](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/commit/735d34260814f9180b773723fd741a7da73047ed)) to support reading from HTTP requests, which looks like it unintentionally fixes this issue. What PIL does here by forcing `.seek(0)` breaks the use cases for users that wants to read from container/concatenated archives without decompressing or making additional copies. I guess they probably consider that use case rather niche compared to HTTP request objects.