# BytesIO object to image

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use Pillow in my program to save a bytestring from my camera to a file. Here's an example with a small raw byte string from my camera which should represent a greyscale image of resolution 10x5 pixels, using LSB and 12bit:

```
import io
from PIL import Image

rawBytes = b'_\x00`\x00[\x00^\x00`\x00`\x00\\\x00\\\x00Z\x00\\\x00_\x00[\x00\\\x00\\\x00`\x00]\x00\\\x00^\x00_\x00\\\x00\\\x00]\x00]\x00_\x00]\x00]\x00Z\x00\\\x00^\x00\\\x00Z\x00^\x00_\x00]\x00^\x00Z\x00\\\x00Z\x00\\\x00]\x00_\x00]\x00^\x00Z\x00[\x00[\x00X\x00]\x00]\x00Z\x00'
rawIO = io.BytesIO(rawBytes)
rawIO.seek(0)
byteImg = Image.open(rawIO)
byteImg.save('test.png', 'PNG')
```

However I get the following error in line 7 (with `Image.open`):

```
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000000041FC9A8>
```

The docs from [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombuffer) implied this was the way to go.

I tried to apply the solutions from

- [PIL open() method not working with BytesIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587426/pil-open-method-not-working-with-bytesio)
- [PIL cannot identify image file for io.BytesIO object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077366/pil-cannot-identify-image-file-for-io-bytesio-object?lq=1)

but can't get it working. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what the resulting image should look like (do you have an example?), but if you want to unpack an packed image where each pixel has 12 bits into a 16-bit image, you could use this code:

```
import io
from PIL import Image

rawbytes = b'_\x00`\x00[\x00^\x00`\x00`\x00\\\x00\\\x00Z\x00\\\x00_\x00[\x00\\\x00\\\x00`\x00]\x00\\\x00^\x00_\x00\\\x00\\\x00]\x00]\x00_\x00]\x00]\x00Z\x00\\\x00^\x00\\\x00Z\x00^\x00_\x00]\x00^\x00Z\x00\\\x00Z\x00\\\x00]\x00_\x00]\x00^\x00Z\x00[\x00[\x00X\x00]\x00]\x00Z\x00'
im = Image.frombuffer("I;16", (5, 10), rawbytes, "raw", "I;12")
im.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! In my case, the output was a Windows WORD type (so 16-bit little endian unsigned integer). In the end, having a look at the [decoder description](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/writing-your-own-file-decoder.html?highlight=unsigned#decoding-floating-point-data), I was able to decode my image correctly: `Image.frombuffer("F", (10, 5), rawbytes, "raw", "F;16")`

Comment: I'm glad the frombuffer() function did for you what you required, and that my suggestion put you on the right track. I did have to delve into the pillow source code to find this solution, however ;-)