# How to extract a byte string from a response using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a python library urllib3. The service I am calling returns a byte string

```
        https = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)

        Response = https.request(method='GET', url=f"https://smart/mem/2.0/files/{fileId}/content", headers=headers)
```

I want to be able to store this byte string in a variable and convert to an image later.

How can I extract the byte string from my response?

Comment: I mean a base64 string rather

Comment: `base64.b64encode(Response.data)`?

Comment: I got a string back and it is not meaningful. I should be able to convert the string returned to an image. I don't think the base64 line of code above works

Comment: then simply `data = Response.data`, and you should be able to convert `data` back to an image.

Comment: Same thing. Not meaningful. Coming back with a bunch of \x01.

Comment: @Baba There are ways to convert those into images, see e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/32210710/9987623.