# Convert PDF page to image with PyPDF2 and BytesIO

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, bytesio

I have a function that gets a page from a PDF file via `PyPDF2` and should convert the first page to a png (or jpg) with `Pillow` (PIL Fork)

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import os
from PIL import Image
import io

# Open PDF Source #
app_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
src_pdf= PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(app_path, "../../../uploads/%s" % filename), "rb"))

# Get the first page of the PDF #
dst_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
dst_pdf.addPage(src_pdf.getPage(0))

# Create BytesIO #
pdf_bytes = io.BytesIO()
dst_pdf.write(pdf_bytes)
pdf_bytes.seek(0)

file_name = "../../../uploads/%s_p%s.png" % (name, pagenum)
img = Image.open(pdf_bytes)
img.save(file_name, 'PNG')
pdf_bytes.flush()
```

That results in an error:

> OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000023440F3A8E0>

I found some threads with a similar issue, ([PIL open() method not working with BytesIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587426/pil-open-method-not-working-with-bytesio)) but I cannot see where I am wrong here, as I have `pdf_bytes.seek(0)` already added.

Any hints appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per document:

> write(stream) Writes the collection of pages added to this object out
>   as a **PDF** file.
>
> Parameters:   stream – An object to write the file to. The object must
>   support the write method and the tell method, similar to a file
>   object.

So the object pdf_bytes contains a PDF file, not an image file.

The reason why there are codes like above work is: sometimes, the pdf file just contains a jpeg file as its content. If your pdf is just a normal pdf file, you can't just read the bytes and parse it as an image.

And refer to as a more robust implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34116472/334999

Answer (score -1):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
import glob, sys, fitz

# To get better resolution
zoom_x = 2.0  # horizontal zoom
zoom_y = 2.0  # vertical zoom
mat    = fitz.Matrix(zoom_x, zoom_y)  # zoom factor 2 in each dimension


filename = "/xyz/abcd/1234.pdf"  # name of pdf file you want to render
doc = fitz.open(filename)
for page in doc:
    pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix=mat)  # render page to an image
    pix.save("/xyz/abcd/1234.png")  # store image as a PNG
```

**Credit**

[Convert PDF to Image in Python Using PyMuPDF][2]

https://towardsdatascience.com/convert-pdf-to-image-in-python-using-pymupdf-9cc8f602525b