# OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at ... > when trying to predict with Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras

I was following a "Deploy Keras neural network to Flask web service" tutorial by deeplizard on YouTube, but got stuck.
I found several suggestions to similar problems which have helped others (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077366/pil-cannot-identify-image-file-for-io-bytesio-object/46394242) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587426/pil-open-method-not-working-with-bytesio)), but for some reason they aren't working for me. Or maybe I'm applying them wrong.

It's upset with the line `image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))`.

Here is the code I have (sorry it's not minimal, I'm not sure how to simplify it without dropping details that might be relevant).

If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Much appreciated.

```
app = Flask(__name__)


def get_model():
    global model, graph
    model = load_model('model.h5')
    print(' * Model loaded!')
    graph = tf.Graph()


def preprocess_image(image, target_size):
    if image.mode != 'RGB':
        image = image.convert('RGB')
    image = image.resize(target_size)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

    return image


print(' * Loading model...')
get_model()


@app.route('/predict', methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    encoded = message['image']
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    with graph.as_default():
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        preprocessed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size(50, 50))
        prediction = model.predict(preprocessed_image).tolist()

        response = {
            'prediction': {
                'food': prediction[0][0],
                'notfood': prediction[0][1]
            }
        }
    return jsonify(response)
```

I suspect it might be because my model takes input as:

`model.predict_classes(i.reshape((-1, 50, 50, 3)), batch_size=32, verbose=0)[0]`

but the images uploaded through html by user aren't' getting reshaped ... I was trying to finagle that into the code, but no luck so far.

Comment: What's the format of the image you are trying to load?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, jpg. I'd like to figure out how to allow for multiple formats, but first I just want to get it working

Comment: What is the `Image` class you are using? Please provide full error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same problem. There was no issue with the target size as it will depend on the target size of images in dataset your deployed model was trained on.

Anyway, problem lies with the type of image (png/jpg) you are sending to the server from client's end. Make sure in the below code line (clientside.html)

base64Image = dataURL.replace("data:image/png;base64,","");

you specifically mentioned **png** and you are also sending the same type of image like **imagename.png** (png images).

I hope this might helpt