# Saving an image from webpage using request

Tags: python, image, request

There is an image on a webpage which I would like to save on my disk using python. 
What I tried to do was

```
r=requests.get(url, timeout=60)
p=os.path.sep.join([args["output"],"{}.jpeg".format(str(total).zfill(5))])
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```

But I realized that the file saved is not in image format as

```
$file name_of_file  
00018.jpeg: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

Then I tried to:

```
    r=requests.get(url, timeout=60)
    p=os.path.sep.join([args["output"],"{}.jpeg".format(str(total).zfill(5))])
    f=open(p, "wb")
    i=r.raw
    q=Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
    print(q.type)
    f.write(i)
    f.close()
```

But with no success. What should I do?

UPDATE:

```
r = requests.get(url, timeout=60)
    # save the image to disk
    p = os.path.sep.join([args["output"], "{}.jpeg".format(
    str(total).zfill(5))])

    with open("test.jpeg","wb+") as f:
        f.write(requests.get("name_of_website",headers=headers).content)


    f.close()
```

When I copied the image manually from the web using cursor, it was a jpg format.

Comment: What's the url?Is it a image file?

Comment: It only has an image

Comment: `Service Interruption`....Could you visited this page normally?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA added the screenshot. The website probably works only on certain regions

Comment: Why did you use `f=open(xxx)`?Could you just run my example to download the image to check the image content?And,the image name is `test.jpg` not `00008.jpg`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211469/discussion-between-hrushi-and-jizhihaosama).

Answer (score 2):

This page needs cookie to do that:
[image]

If not,you can not visit it directly.

An easy way is add a cookie in your request header:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Cookie":"visid_incap_276192=vO9ugmNqRS+XGehZnF1jiwL8kl4AAAAAQUIPAAAAAADc6Z+46+Lp6X9DL0FUaSOv; incap_ses_627_276192=HgPZUq1t1yD2FURXnY2zCAL8kl4AAAAAyQ+1ZeYdSVzPTcurvHnlwA==; JSESSIONID=0001Zh35TV6HDxcVflnHMwIHsqe:-1801K8D; incap_ses_553_276192=XuxOZn9AsVOTcVuFwKasB3P9kl4AAAAAaxsIzIzT5BwV8RqhcTVPsw==",
}

with open("test.jpg","wb+") as f:
    f.write(requests.get("https://www.e-zpassny.com/vector/jcaptcha.do",headers=headers).content)
```

Now it can download the image successfully:
[image]

Comment: The files get downloaded by when I open them they're empty. `file 00008.jpg' gives 
`00008.jpg: empty`

Comment: I have updated my question on how I ran the script, I also added the cookies

Comment: Why don't use `print(response.context)` to check the bytes of response?if it is `b'xxxxx'`,represents you visit the image successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do someting like this:

```
r = requests.get(url, timeout=60)
q = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
fp = os.path.join([args["output"], f"{str(total).zfill(5)}.jpeg"]) # here i used f-string because it looks more compact 
q = q.save(fp)
```

Image.save() described [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) 
F-strings it's way of formatting, it described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/)

I hope that it's helpful, have a good day!

EDIT:
Ok it looks like it doesn't work
So, you can try this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587426/pil-open-method-not-working-with-bytesio):

```
r = requests.get(url, timeout=60)

bytes = BytesIO(r.content)
bytes.seek(0)
q = Image.ope(bytes)

fp = os.path.join([args["output"], f"{str(total).zfill(5)}.jpeg"]) # here i used f-string because it looks more compact 
q = q.save(fp)
```

Comment: I got this error `"cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7febf9fcfa98>` at the line q=Image.open(Byt...).

Comment: For a strange reason, I get the same error. Is there any other way to extract the image without using requests

Comment: @Hrushi I don't know but I am sure that you can show image with using `Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)).show()`, because I've done that some time ago. Actually, I don't know how to do this without requests, but I think if you can show it, also you can save it in a folder. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31077366/13283436) can help you.