# Unable to convert imgkit image to PIL image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imgkit

I am trying to convert an imgkit image into a PIL image to modify it. imgkit successfully converted the html to image when I tried to use a file. When I use BytesIO and try to convert to a PIL image, im getting an error.

Here is my code:

```py
img = imgkit.from_string(template.render(a=elements, r=range(len(elements))), False, config=config)
bytesImg = BytesIO(img)
bytesImg.seek(0)
image = Image.open(bytesImg) #error here
```

> PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x102082680>

I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587426/pil-open-method-not-working-with-bytesio) and [this](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3431).
Am I incorrectly converting the imgkit image to bytes or is there some other error?

Using Pillow 8.1 Python 3.9 and imgkit 1.0.2

Comment: What are the first 20 bytes of `bytesImg` please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell . I used a print(bytesImg.read()) and got b'%PDF-1.4\n1 0 obj\n<<\n'.
if that is what you are asking for

Comment: That looks like a PDF which PIL can only write, not read https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html Can you force ImgKit to generate a JPEG?

Comment: Yeah, it worked. I messed up the config variable and it converted it to a pdf instead of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imgkit was converting the html to pdf because the config variable was messed up.

use

```
which wkhtmltoimage
```

to find path to wkhtmltoimage and set

```
config = imgkit.config(wkhtmltoimage="path found")
```

Answer (score 1):

*Am I incorrectly converting the imgkit image to bytes or is there some other error?*

I would start from checking if your bytes represents image understand by your Pillow. Built-in module [imghdr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html) should suffice if you are excepting one of format known by it (see table in docs). Usage in this case:

```
import imghdr
```

...

```
print(imghdr.what(None, h=img))
```

If it does identify format then check if it is supported by your Pillow, else you would need to manually check [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) (few starting bytes).

Comment: I tried imghdr.what(None, h=img) and got 'jpeg'.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. my config variable was messed up and converted to pdf in my main code. it didn't show up in testing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For different version of python/Pillow/imgkit (in my case they were 3.6.9/8.4.0/1.2.3) experienced similar problem.

> PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO
> object at 0x102082680>

Check with

> print(imghdr.what(None, h=img))

showed `None`

When printing first bytes, turned out that there was additional output from imgkit/wkhtmltoimage

> b'libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile\nlibpng warning:
> iCCP: known incorrect sRGB
> profile\n\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00d\x00d\x00\x00\xff

the workaround was to trim first bytes containing warning information ('quiet' option didn't resolve the issue).

> img = imgkit.from_string(content, False, options={"xvfb": "", "quiet":
> ""})

> img = img[102:]